# No code coverage driver is available in xampp windows

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, lumen

I want to run phpunit testcase with codecoverage report and for that i am using following command:

```
D:\xampp7.1.9\htdocs\mailzap>phpunit --coverage-html reports
```

output:

```
PHPUnit 6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Error:         No code coverage driver is available

.                                                  1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 469 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

php@version : 7.1.9  phpunit@version:6.3.0
but still converge report not generated.
in lumen framework

Comment: The reason may be xdebug is not enabled for php cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you have XDebug installed and configured correctly.

A guide can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed) for where to download it from and get it set up correctly